# yellowbrick module instalation affects matplotlib fonts avaliable

Tags: matplotlib, fonts, yellowbrick

After instalation and import of yellowbrick module matplotlib can't find some of the fonts for its labels and titles like Arial, Liberation Sans, Bitstream Vera Sans, sans-serif

the following warning appears:
´´´
findfont: Generic family 'sans-serif' not found because none of the following families were found: Arial, Liberation Sans, Bitstream Vera Sans, sans-serif
´´´

even graph vizualization is affected, looking something like seaborn wolud produce

the first image its normal and represents what it should be the output
[image]

Next one is with the module import
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue last week. The following steps worked for me.

1. Uninstalled yellowbrick via pip
2. Restarted my notebook
3. Imported font-manager from matplotlib.
   import matplotlib.font-manager

I no longer encounter the font not found issue. You can try without step 3 to see if that would work. If not, try again after importing font-manager.